# Fetching data from a website using "POST" request

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I've written some code in vba for the purpose of making twofold "POST" requests to get to the destination page and  harvest name and address from there. There are two types of structures within which the desired results lie. One type of structure holds name and address in a single "th" storage and the other holds name in one "td" and address in another "td". So, to handle this I had to use error handler to get the most out of it. By using xmlhttp I could not get any result so I used WinHttpRequest in my script to get the result by enabling redirection. My script is running errorlessly at this moment. However, any suggestion to improve my code specially by handling error more efficiently will be highly appreciated.

Here is the full working code:

```
Sub reverse_scraping()

    Dim http As New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest, html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim posts As Object, post As Object
    Dim ArgStr As String, ArgStr_ano As String, cNo As String, cName As String

    For Each cel In Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)

        If cel.Value <> "" Then
            cNo = cel.Value
            cName = Replace(cel.Offset(0, 1).Value, " ", "+")
        End If

        ArgStr = "search=addr"
        ArgStr_ano = "TaxYear=2017&stnum=" & cNo & "&stname=" & cName

        With http
            .Option(6) = True
            .Open "POST", "https://public.hcad.org/records/QuickSearch.asp", False
            .setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36"
            .setRequestHeader "Referer", "https://public.hcad.org/records/quicksearch.asp"
            .send ArgStr
        End With

        With http
            .Option(6) = True
            .Open "POST", "https://public.hcad.org/records/QuickRecord.asp", False
            .setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36"
            .setRequestHeader "Referer", "https://public.hcad.org/records/quicksearch.asp"
            .send ArgStr_ano
            html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        End With

        On Error Resume Next
        Set posts = html.getElementsByClassName("data")(2).getElementsByTagName("th")
        Set post = html.getElementsByClassName("bgcolor_1")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")(1).getElementsByTagName("td")

        If posts.Length Or post.Length Then
            cel.Offset(0, 2) = posts(0).innerText
            cel.Offset(0, 2) = post(1).innerText
            cel.Offset(0, 3) = post(2).innerText
        End If

    Next cel
End Sub
```

Here are the two links to show how to reach the destination page (in first link it is needed to click on the "search by address" button to get the search option):

1 https://www.dropbox.com/s/e9on9zwqzmcboze/1Untitled.jpg?dl=0

2 https://www.dropbox.com/s/0lchpde8uq63jps/pics.jpg?dl=0

search to be made using the below documents placing those in column "A" and "B" respectively and results will be placed in column "c" to the corresponding cells.

```
Street No   Street Name
6330        LAUTREC DR
5522        DARLING ST
7411        SANDLE ST
10234       LUCORE ST
```